# Why my modules are optimized, even if try to avoid

Tags: requirejs

main.js config:

```
requirejs.config({
baseUrl : "./js",
paths : {
  'jquery' : 'libs/jquery-1.9.1.min',
  'jqm' : 'libs/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min',
  'json' : 'libs/jquery.json-2.4.min',
  'jcache' : 'libs/jqache-0.1.1.min',
  'cordova' : 'libs/cordova', 
  'fb' : 'libs/facebook-js-sdk',
  'fbc' : 'libs/cdv-plugin-fb-connect',
  'photoswipe' : 'libs/code.photoswipe.jquery-3.0.5.min',
  'klass' : 'libs/klass.min',
  'mustache' : 'libs/mustache',
  'domReady' : 'libs/domReady'
},
shim : {
  'jqm' : {
    deps : ['jqm-init']
  },
  'json' : {
    deps : ['jquery']
  },
  'jcache' : {
    deps : ['jquery']
  },
  'photoswipe' : {
    deps : ['jquery', 'klass'],
    exports : 'Code.PhotoSwipe'
  },
  'fbc' : {
    exports : 'CDV'
  },
  'fb' : {
    exports : 'FB'
  },
  'mustache' : {
    exports : 'Mustache'
  }
}
```

});

build.js

```
({
  baseUrl : "js/",
  mainConfigFile : './js/main.js',
  paths : {
    'jquery' : 'empty:',
    'jqm' : 'empty:',
    'json' : 'empty:',
    'jcache' : 'empty:',
    'cordova' : 'empty:',
    'fb' : 'empty:',
    'fbc' : 'empty:',
    'photoswipe' : 'empty:',
    'klass' : 'empty:',
    'mustache' : 'empty:',
    'domReady' : 'empty:',
  },
  stubModules: ['jquery',
                'jqm',
                'json',
                'jcache',
                'cordova',
                'fb',
                'fbc',
                'photoswipe',
                'klass',
                'mustache',
                'domReady'],
  name : "main",

  optimize : "closure",
  closure : {
    CompilerOptions : {},
    CompilationLevel : 'SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATIONS',
    loggingLevel : 'WARNING'
  },
  optimizeCss : "standard",
})
```

Even if the already minimized libs are set to emtpy: and marked as stubs r.js optimize them? What I am doing wrong?